# How can I send order Id in the url and get response?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

> Here is my code And After execute this code i got this error "Response : {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://example.com/Api/WooCommerceApi/SaveSubscriptionAndZoomData'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'WooCommerceApi' that matches the request."}"

```
function my_api_call( $order_id ){

    // Order Setup Via WooCommerce

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // Iterate Through Items

    $items = $order->get_items();

    $url = "http://example.com/Api/WooCommerceApi/SaveSubscriptionAndZoomData";

    $orderid = "OrderId=".$order_id;

    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $orderid);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec( $ch );

     write_log ("Order Id for new user: " .$orderid ." and Response is : ".$response);

     }
     add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'my_api_call');
```

> I hope You will understad may question. And I want to print Json
>   response also in the file

Comment: If you want to send the order id in the url, you need a GET parameters. right now, you are using a post parameters ( `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` ). you could simply append it to the url : `'http:// .../..ZoomData?OrderId=' . $order_id`

Comment: Also, from your edit, the endpoint you are trying to reach does not exists.

Comment: how I add get perameters in the code ?

Comment: whats this meant to endpoint trying to reach does not exists?

Comment: will you explain these details

Comment: `$post['OrderId'] = $order_id;` and `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);`

Comment: The endpoint "http://example.com/Api/WooCommerceApi/SaveSubscriptionAndZoomData" does not exist, is what Nicolas is trying to say.